# Text not showing on iPad

Tags: html, ipad

I have a question, I’m making this page to show the stores and contacts of a local store, and the problem it’s when you watch the page on a iPad, the contact numbers are not showing, I have tried to create a class for the numbers and to put them some color, but I have cannot make the numbers to appear, the weird thing is that some of the numbers are shown but most of them look like have a white color.
Here’s the page http://comohogar.com/contactos.php

I hope you guys can help me with this.
Just in case I know that’s not responsive, yet, I’m working in that later

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad and iPhone love to identify phone numbers and let you click/touch them. My best guess is that iPad is turning the contact numbers into links, which are globally set to white (#FFFFFF) in your style sheet. Try adding this to your css:

```
#telefono a {
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

**Also**, a style *ID* should only be used once on a page. 
A style *class* can be reused over and over on the same page. I strongly recommend changing all the repeating IDs you're using into classes. For example, change `<div id="telefono">` to `<div class="telefono">` and then change the css to:

```
.telefono a {
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: thanks!! I will use your recommendation!! I'm still in the learning process XD, also i found useful using the <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">, this way it block the iPad and iPhone tho find this numbers for contacts